# Re-route traffic from a Shadowsocks server based on GeoIP

Tags: linux, proxy, squid, socks

I am trying to set up a proxy network consisting of two servers:

First server is a ShadowSocks server (Rust version) with manager API enabled as a standalone systemd service. This allows opening proxy ports dynamically for each new user. Now I need to add a feature where I re-route traffic that requests a certain region (based on GeoIP) and re-routes it to another server which has a tinyproxy (SOCKS5) enabled on a single port. I thought of using Squid for that, since they claim to support SOCKS5 but I didn't find any documentation besides compilation instructions. How would I set this up?

To summarize:

```
Server A:
[shadowsocks-rust / ssmanager] -> opens SS on random port from 1024 to 99999 -> if IP matches region, re-route to another SOCKS server
Server B:
tinyproxy SOCKS5 listening on port 3333
```

for additional info:
I also dynamically modify the firewall on Server A by invoking UFW to only allow proxy ports. And my server runs Arch Linux.